# Should I use JSON or XML?

Tags: xml, json

I have a series of .NET WCF RESTFul services that can produce either JSON or XML format responses.  These services will be used by android java clients.  I'm presently an android/java newbie.

Which format is easier to process.  Which is faster.

Since they are my own services I don't care to much about type-safety.
Thanks,
Gary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON typically is a bit more lightweight, so if bandwidth is a concern (given that you're targeting Android devices, it might very well be) I'd say JSON. Also, if you want to open up your services to JavaScript in a web browser, JS (and JS developers) is (are) probably happier to receive JSON.

XML is nice, I suppose, if you want to use schemas or if you're doing JAXB stuff or something.

Answer (score 2):

I think both have become pretty standard these days. I guess one argument in favor of JSON is that it's less verbose. However on the flip side most developers seem to still be more comfortable with xml.

Comment: It's also a matter of which one has better support in the framework you are using

Answer (score 1):

JSON is more readable and more maintainable. I have used both and I prefer JSON in most cases. It's up to you, which one are you more comfortable with.

Comment: Readability is an excellent point in favor of JSON (at least in my opinion), good call! Also, in case it was ambiguous in my answer, I tend to lean heavily toward JSON.